# Xcode Remove View with Scenes in Storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard

How do I remove the entire left column from storyboard? It takes up a lot of space.

I apologize if it's a dumb question, I've looked everywhere but couldn't find an answer.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't want to *remove* the view but just *hide*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a button right there. Check XCode screenshot

[image]